# Oracle: How to restart row_number function

Tags: oracle, row-number

I have a scenario where in I need to assign row_number for a data grouped by department, branch, amount and ordering by date. 
If the amount repeats after some dates for the same department & branch, I would like to have the row_number as 1.
Could you please let me know how to achieve this?
When I tried with Row_number function the numbering is continuing after some dates.

Sample Data:
This is the row numbers I am getting if the following function is used `row_number() over(Partition by Department, Branch, Amount order by Date)`

```
Department  Branch  Amount  Date        Row_number()
Dep A       Bran 1  51      25-Oct-12   1
Dep A       Bran 1  45.5    26-Nov-12   1
Dep A       Bran 1  45.5    05-Apr-13   2
Dep A       Bran 1  45.5    06-May-13   3
Dep A       Bran 1  65      07-May-13   1
Dep A       Bran 1  51      26-Aug-13   2
Dep A       Bran 1  51      11-Sep-13   3
```

But I am expecting output in the below order.

```
Department  Branch  Amount  Date        Row_number()
Dep A       Bran 1  51      25-Oct-12   1
Dep A       Bran 1  45.5    26-Nov-12   1
Dep A       Bran 1  45.5    05-Apr-13   2
Dep A       Bran 1  45.5    06-May-13   3
Dep A       Bran 1  65      07-May-13   1
Dep A       Bran 1  51      26-Aug-13   1
Dep A       Bran 1  51      11-Sep-13   2
```

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change how you identify the groups inside which you calculate `row_number()`.

Something like:

```
SQL> with t (Department,  Branch,  Amount,  Date#)
  2  as (
  3  select 'Dep A',   'Bran 1',  51,  to_date('25-10-2012','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
  4  select 'Dep A',  'Bran 1',  45.5,    to_date('26-11-2012','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
  5  select 'Dep A',   'Bran 1',  45.5,    to_date('05-04-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
  6  select 'Dep A',   'Bran 1', 45.5,    to_date('06-05-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
  7  select 'Dep A',   'Bran 1',  65,  to_date('07-05-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
  8  select 'Dep A',   'Bran 1',  51,  to_date('26-08-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual union all
  9  select 'Dep A',   'Bran 1',  51,  to_date('11-09-2013','DD-MM-YYYY') from dual
 10  )
 11  select department, branch, amount, date#, row_number() over(partition by grp order by date#) rn
 12  from (
 13  select department, branch, amount, date#, sum(st_grp) over(order by date#) grp from (
 14  select department, branch, amount, date#, case when amount = lag(amount,1,amount) over(order by date#) then 0 else 1 end st_grp from t
 15  )
 16  )
 17  order by date#
 18  /

DEPAR BRANCH     AMOUNT DATE#            RN                                     
----- ------ ---------- -------- ----------                                     
Dep A Bran 1         51 25.10.12          1                                     
Dep A Bran 1       45,5 26.11.12          1                                     
Dep A Bran 1       45,5 05.04.13          2                                     
Dep A Bran 1       45,5 06.05.13          3                                     
Dep A Bran 1         65 07.05.13          1                                     
Dep A Bran 1         51 26.08.13          1                                     
Dep A Bran 1         51 11.09.13          2
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the info. This query worked for the same Dept, Branch. If the branch or dept or both changes, could you please let me know how to alter the query?